# Add a custom section to Category products section in using Custom module magento2

Tags: magento2, product, category

Can anyone help me, how to add a custom section for category products section using custom module in magento2.

Please find the screenshot below.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please try with the below code which will help you how to add custom section to the category landing page from your custom module.

> app/code/Magently/Ajax/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="category.product.addto">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="magently.ajax.info2" template="Magently_Ajax::test.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>        
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/code/Magently/Ajax/view/frontend/templates/test.phtml

```
<?php echo "Custom Template" ?>
```

Please note:- may be the above code will not give exact result...change the reference container name and try it from your end.

**class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"** based on your requirement you can change the block class.

Comment: Hi @nagaraju Can you please tell me what is the exact container name i wants to use in place "category.product.addto"

Comment: let me know whether the above code is working?

Comment: Hi @nagaraju any update on this

Comment: No @shivashankarm